# How to call main-menu twice on page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu

I have a website built with wordpress 4.5.3 on a free QUILL theme.

I decided to create a sticky menu by making a div that would only appear after a 100vh scroll and in this div to display the main menu.

I copied the main menu code:

```
    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
    <button class="menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
    </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
```

and everything seemed to work fine until I took a look on mobile and noticed that only one of the menus work when clicking on the "burger".

So my question is what would be the best way to display the main menu twice on a page without any problem in mobile?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the different IDs for  tag then both will work properly, there may be css you need to copy for old ID or you can use "HTML Class"

```
 <nav id="site-navigation1" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
    <button class="menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
    </nav>

 <nav id="site-navigation2" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
    <button class="menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
```

To

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'Main Menu' ) ); ?>
```

'Main Menu' can be other names also, just check it from your admin panel